# Does the self-reference effect extend to improved recall of 2nd-person text vs. 3rd-person text?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, memory

The [self-reference effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Reference_Effect) has been widely [researched](http://www.carlsonschool.umn.edu/Assets/71676.pdf) in marketing for its ability to improve how favorably consumers remember a message, but less so for its ability to improve recall and learning of text. For example, whether the following information

```
You bought some milk and cheese.
```

would be more effectively recalled than

```
He bought some milk and cheese.
```

The self-reference effect appears to improve information encoding by using autobiographical memory, but does any work  specifically look at relationships between using the 2nd or 3rd person and learning/recall?